# Why use an immediately invoked function to create a new object?

Tags: javascript

In a book i'm reading called *Testable JavaScript*, the following code pattern is used (ignore the specifics):

```
var Obj = (function() {
    return function() {
        var docRoot = '/somewhere';
        this.validateDocRoot = function(val) {
            // validation logic - throw Error if not OK
        };
        this.setDocRoot = function(val) {
            this.validateDocRoot(val);
            docRoot = val;
        };
        this.getDocRoot = function() {
            return docRoot;
        };
    };
}());

var myObject = new Obj();
```

But why treat Obj as an immediately invoked function?  That is, what's the difference between this pattern and the following code pattern:

```
var Obj = function() {
        var docRoot = '/somewhere';
        this.validateDocRoot = function(val) {
            // validation logic - throw Error if not OK
        };
        this.setDocRoot = function(val) {
            this.validateDocRoot(val);
            docRoot = val;
        };
        this.getDocRoot = function() {
            return docRoot;
        };
    };

var myObject = new Obj();
```

Isn't it the case that `myObject` is the same in both cases?

Comment: In this particular example I see no advantage to using the anonymous function wrapper. There's nothing declared in the wrapper so there's no use made of the closure.

Comment: @Pointy That comment implicitly answers the question.

Comment: My guess is that later in the book they introduce private class variables within the IIFE. For now it's unnecessary.

Comment: *"But why treat Obj as an immediately invoked function?"* `Obj` **isn't** an IIFE. It's a variable referring to a function *returned by* the IIFE.

Comment: @Vohuman I was going to ask the OP if there was any other context but I had to go get more coffee first :)  OP, is that function extended in subsequent examples? It could be that the author wanted to establish that code structure and then incrementally add pieces to go along with some explanatory sequence.

Comment: Examples are almost always too simple to be interesting/useful.  The point is to get used to the new way of doing things; then you will be ready when you really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in your example.
Often immediately invoked function is used to implement the module pattern (http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) which helps you to encapsulate data you do not want to be in global scope.

You example can be rewritten as

```
var myObject = (function() {
    var docRoot = '/somewhere';
    return {
        validateDocRoot : function(val) {
            // validation logic - throw Error if not OK
        },
        setDocRoot : function(val) {
            this.validateDocRoot(val);
            docRoot = val;
        },
        getDocRoot : function() {
            return docRoot;
        }
    };
}());
```

In this case using of immediately invoked function is really matter. In your first example it only adds syntax noise.